# Get the drop downListFor show the selected value in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a DropDownListFor is like this  below

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m._dayOfWeek, new SelectList(Model._dayOfWeekList, "Value", "Text"))

in Model 

_dayOfWeek is string
_dayOfWeekList is List<selectlistItem>
```

now in `dayOfWeekList` is getting created in controller and it can have many values  but max seven values

Value - 0  Text - Monday

Value - 1  Text - Tuesday

Value - 2  Text - Wednesday

and so on ...

now in _dayOfWeek string i can assign value or text  - depending on the value in 
`_dayOfWeek`   --- the dropdown  should be able to show that option

when the page is loaded drop down is always showing Monday as default .

how to make the drop down show that option which is there in `_dayOfWeek` string

Comment: Question: _dayOfWeek property (or variable) in your model is a int? (or something that can hold 0, 1.. or 6.

Comment: What is the data type for `Value` in the `_dayOfWeekList`?

Comment: all the things are property and all are strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't create a new `SelectList`. Razor can handle this itself, and it's better to let it. All `DropDownListFor` requires is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, which you already have:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m._dayOfWeek, Model._dayOfWeekList)
```

Second, the value assigned is determined based on `ModelState`, which is composed of values from `Request`, `ViewData`/`ViewBag` and, as a last resort, `Model`. As a result, you should ensure that your view's model has the appropriate value set for that property *and* that it aligns with the possible option values in your `List<SelectListItem>`. Then, ensure that you do not have any conflicts from accepting a param like `_dayOfWeek` to your action method or something like `ViewBag._dayOfWeek` being set to some value. In both cases, casing does not matter, so `_dayOfWeek` == `_DayOfWeek` == `_DAYOFWEEK`.

Comment: Its not working  - I am making the correct Item Selected  = true in the DropDowList and in view its also showing while debugging I can see the item hold Seleted porperty true - still when its loaded its getting default Monday loaded

Comment: The `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is completely ignored by Razor. Again, Razor sets the value based on what's in `ModelState`, regardless of your manual `Selected` settings.  If the right value isn't being selected, then there's a problem with the value in `ModelState`, which is what you'll have to look at and determine *why* it's incorrect there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the answer to that  . without using viewbag or viewdata

```
       foreach (var item in model._dayOfWeekList)
        {
          if (item.Text == model._dayOfWeek)
         {
               item.Selected = true;
            }

        }
```

thnaks to others also for their time